# Не могу подключить скаченный шрифт html

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Скачал хороший шрифт с какого то сайта и хочу его использовать в своем коде, но понятия не имею как его подключить. Пробовал несколько способов и все были безуспешны.
Никогда до этого не скачивал шрифты скаченные с внешних ресурсов. Буду очень признателен всем за помощь.

[image: итог]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шрифты подключаются при помощи стилей, например

```
<style>
@font-face{
   font-family:"myfont"; //здесь даем название шрифту
   src: url("fonts/myfont.ttf"); //здесь указываем путь до шрифта
}
.mystyle{
font-family: "myfont"; //задаем название шрифта для класса
}
</style>

<body>
<p class="mystyle">Мой текст</p>
</body>
```